# ServiceNow File content corrupted when calling Attachment API

Tags: c#, servicenow-rest-api

I'm calling the ServiceNow Attachment API to upload files but they are ending up corrupted even though they upload successfully.

```
ServiceNow Attachment API 
POST https://sn-host.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=YOURTABLE&table_sys_id=SYSID&file_name=FILENAME
```

A simple text file with content "test" is corrupted and the content looks like this:

```
-----------3056BD41-FD91-4B8C-8BCD-E35A47CAA7A3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="b.txt"
Content-Type: application/x-gzip

test
-----------3056BD41-FD91-4B8C-8BCD-E35A47CAA7A3--
```

I'm using C# / RestSharp to call the upload api:

```
private static bool UploadFileBytes(byte[] file_bytes, string file_name, string table_name, string table_sys_id, string content_type)
{
    bool retval = false;
    try
    {
        string URL = SN_Srv_dest + $"/api/now/attachment/file?table_name={table_name}&table_sys_id={table_sys_id}&file_name={file_name}";
        Console.WriteLine("Post file to SN: " + URL);

        var client = new RestClient(URL);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddFileBytes("file", file_bytes, file_name);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", content_type);
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(SN_Id_dest, SN_Pw_dest);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Post file {file_name} success: {response.Content}");
            retval = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Post file {file_name} failed: {response.Content}");
            retval = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Post file {file_name} failed: {e.Message}");
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue using the generated code in PostMan.  The following line was causing the problem:

```
request.AddFileBytes("file", file_bytes, file_name);
```

I replaced it with this:

```
request.AddParameter("file", file_bytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```